# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'openpyxl' However it is up to date

Tags: python, openpyxl

I have PyCharm as IDE, using python 3.6, and my `openpyxl` version is `3.0.0` 
However, when I run:

```
import openpyxl
```

I get

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'openpyxl'`

Why is this happening?

Comment: PyCharm often creates a virtual environment for your project. If `openpyxl` was installed from command-line, it will not be installed for your virtual environment.

Comment: I updated `openpyxl` via the Menus in Pycharm, going to Project Interpreter

Comment: Did it work before updating?

Comment: Actually it did.

Comment: That is strange. The best thing to try is just uninstall then reinstall (I can't think of anything better!)

Comment: Reinstall Pycharm, or just `openpyxl` ?

Comment: Sorry, just `openpyxl` as it was possible `pip` encountered problems when updating (which PyCharm may not have realised).